# Need a overall scoring algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, scoring

I have a number of words divided into different categories. each word has assigned with a rank between 0 to 100. I am checking in the text if a word appears in a text, I want to find an overall score for a particular category.

For Example, Let's consider, I have General Category and I have a couple of words on the same category

| word | weight | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 90 | 5 |
| y | 84 | 4 |
| z | 52 | 2 |

the count is how many times word appear in the text

Currently, I am using the LOG-SUM-EXP(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) method to calculate the score for a category.
For the above table, the score would be 91.61

```
SELECT LOG(EXP(90) + EXP(90) + EXP(90) + EXP(90) + EXP(90) + EXP(84) + EXP(84) + EXP(84) + EXP(84) + EXP(52) + EXP(52));
```

Things to consider while scoring

1. count of word and weight

The problem I am facing is that if there is only one word present with one count, the score would be really high.

For example, the score would be 91 for the below query

```
SELECT LOG(EXP(91))
```

| word | weight | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 91 | 1 |

I don't want a high score if the count is low, Is there any alternative algorithm that can solve the problem?

The final score should be between 0 to 100.

Comment: In your mentioned example with only 1 word, what score would seem acceptable to you?

Comment: Does the "rank between 0 to 1" you mention in your question correspond to the weights between 0 and 100? Also, what does this question have to do with Java or MySQL? It appears to be a purely mathematical or algorithmic question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the weights as values between 0 and 1, rather than between 1-100. With a quick implementation in Python, your example gives:

```
import numpy as np
def lse(L):
    return np.log(sum(map(np.exp, L)))
example_1 = [.9 for _ in range(5)] + [.84 for _ in range(4)] + [.52 for _ in range(2)]
example_2 = [.9]
```

Then:

```
> lse(example_1)
3.2159731667213824
> lse(example_2)
0.9
```

It's intended that LogSumExp of a set containing one element returns that element - this way, though, the other example you gave does have a higher return.